# Laravel 4.0 to 4.1 helpers in Handlerbars templates

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

Why does this code

```
<a href="{{{ url('event',array('id' => '@{{id}}')) }}}">View</a>
```

Worked in Laravel 4.0 and not anymore in 4.1?

One possibles reason from http://laravel.com/docs/releases:

*Laravel 4.1 features a totally re-written routing layer. The API is the same; however, registering routes is a full 100% faster compared to 4.0. The entire engine has been greatly simplified, and the dependency on Symfony Routing has been minimized to the compiling of route expressions.*

Comment: Its not routing. Its something to do with the blade template system.

Comment: I think that before, the blade template system returned something like
"mylink.com/event/{{id}}" and this code was compilable by Handlebar.

Comment: But "how". It cant generate the link, because it doesnt know the ID, because you are wrapping it in a url() function. Are you 100% sure it worked in 4.0? Can you 'roll back' your code and see it work?